# Раскрывающийся список с данными из базы

Tags: jquery, база-данных, php

Из БД данные поступают в поле селект. Пользователи выбирают необходимую категорию, это значение заносится в базу данных. Может кто-нибудь кинуть код, как это делать? Для наглядности.

И еще какпроверить текстовое поле на корректность записи? Например только цифры? Тоько русские буквы и тд? без загрузки дополнительных плагинов.

Answer (score 1):

Форма:

```
<li>
        <label class="description" for="idpersa">Юзер</label>
        <div>
            <select name="idpersa">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<?php 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM characters WHERE account = $myrow2[id] ORDER BY name");
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='".$table["id"]."' >".$table["name"]." </option>";
}
?>
</select>
        </div>
        </li>
```

Обработчик селекта обычный:

```
if (isset($_POST['idpersa'])) {$idpersa = $_POST['idpersa'];}
$idpersa = stripslashes($idpersa);
$idpersa = htmlspecialchars($idpersa);
settype($idpersa,'int'); //если айди не число, обнулит.
```

Ну и дальше просто заносишь в БД:

```
$query = "INSERT into tablename (id и другие данные) VALUES ('$idpersa', и все че нужно другое)";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
```